# Beep command with letters for notes (IBM AT + DOS circa 1984)

Tags: ms-dos, ibm-pc, sound

I'm looking for a reference for a command which used **letters for musical notes**, and would play very **simple tunes with square waves**.  It ran on an **IBM AT**, circa **1984**, which was running a version of IBM/MS DOS.  This hardware had a simple timer to control the speaker.  Circuit diagrams etc were in the Technical Reference manual ([PDF](https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/IBM_5170_Technical_Reference_1502243_MAR84.pdf)) (pages 1-30, 1-76, 1-77).

The notation was something along the lines of

- A single string of ASCII characters
- Something indicated the tempo
- `A`, `A#`, `B`, `C`, `C#`, `D` ... `G#` played a note
- There were characters for "go up/down" an octave
- There was some way to indicate amount of [staccato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staccato)

Do you know what it was?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This sounds like the `PLAY` command in BASIC. It takes a string indicating what to play, with the following notation for the features you mention:

- `A` to `G`, followed by optional `#`, `+`, or `-`, plays the corresponding note
- `On` sets the octave (*n* between 0 and 6), `<` and `>` change octaves
- `Tn` sets the tempo (*n* in quarter-notes per minute, between 32 and 255)
- `MS` enables staccato

See [the IBM BASIC manual](https://archive.org/details/IBMBASICAV1.10Manual/page/n315/) for details. GW-BASIC and QuickBASIC support this command too. See [the Microsoft BASIC MML page](http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_BASIC_MML) on the Video Game Music Preservation Foundation’s wiki for details.

PC Magazine published a similar DOS utility, called `PLAY`, in [volume 6 issue 8 (April 28, 1987)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zx4i2o3UhvEC&lpg=PA297&pg=PA297); it supports the same syntax as the BASIC command. If you used this, you might remember the sample tunes it comes with, The Entertainer (famously featured in *The Sting*) and Greensleeves. It was also included in the [*DOS Power Tools*](https://archive.org/details/DOS_Power_Tools_Paul_Somerson/page/1074) book and in the three-disk set of utilities which was sent to subscribers for a number of years.

Comment: Also information on this at http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_BASIC_MML

Comment: That sounds familiar. I wonder if it was included with the copy of Paul Somerson's DOS Power Tools that I had as a kid. That was badged as PC Magazine DOS Power Tools in the first edition.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of; I didn't remember it was part of BASIC.  Many thanks.